# Is this simplification of boolean algebra correct?

Tags: propositional-calculus

```
CW = A`.B.C`.D` + A.B`.C`.D` + A.B`.C.D` + A.B.C`.D + A.B.C.D`
CW = A`.B.C`.D` + A.B`.D`(C`+C) + A.B(C`.D + C.D`)
CW = A`.B.C`.D` + A.B`.D`(1) + A.B(C`.D +D`.C)
CW = A`.B.C`.D` + A.B`.D` + A.B(C`.1.C)
CW = A`.B.C`.D` + A.B`.D` + A.B(1)
CW = A`.B.C`.D` + A.B`.D` + A.B
CW = A.B + A`.B.C`.D` + A.B`.D`
CW = B(A+A`.C`.D`) + A.B`.D`
CW = B(1.C`.D`) + A.B`.D`
CW = B(1) + A.B`.D`
CW = B + A.B`.D`
CW = B + B`.A.D` 
CW = 1.A.D`
CW = 1
```

Comment: No first step is wrong, ABC\`D + ABCD\` does not equal AB(C\`D + CD\`).

Answer (score 0):

$$\overline A\ B\ \overline C \ \overline D + A\ \overline B \ \overline C\ \overline D + A\overline B C\overline D + AB\overline C D + ABC\overline D$$

Look for common terms.  To eliminate a term, the other 3 must be the same.  Duplicate terms as required.

$$\overline A\ B\ \overline C \ \overline D + (A\ \overline B \ \overline C\ \overline D + A\overline B C\overline D) + AB\overline C D + (ABC\overline D + A\overline B C\overline D)$$
$$\overline A\ B\ \overline C \ \overline D + A\ \overline B \overline D (\overline C\  + C) + AB\overline C D + AC\overline D(B + \overline B)$$
$$\overline A\ B\ \overline C \ \overline D + A\ \overline B\  \overline D + AB\overline C D + AC\overline D$$

Best you can do.